# How do I make the footer stretch vertically downward align to footer

Tags: css

I am new to web design using tableless and I'm having problem positioning some elements on my page..

Here's the sample html: http://christianruado.comuf.com/sample.html [alt text http://christianruado.comuf.com/images/screen.jpg](http://christianruado.comuf.com/images/screen.jpg)

As you can see from the screen shots I want my right div to be vertically stretched down to the same level of my footer and position my bottom element to the lowest part of the right container.

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:88%;
}
#header {
    background:#CCCCCC;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
#content {
    background: #0099CC;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#main {
    margin: .5em 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    width:80%;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width: 19%;
    background:#FF3300;
    margin-left:2px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}
#right .top {
    top:0;
    display:block;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
#right .bottom {
    bottom:0;
    display:block;
    background-color:#FFCCFF;
    height:30px;
}
#center {
    background:#00FF99;
    padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
    float:left;
}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#CCFF33;
    width:80%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="container showgrid">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="right"><span class="top">Top element</span><span class="bottom">Bottom Element</span></div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="center">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>Content here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <h3>Footer</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is it placed in your HTML markup? Can you post some HTML too so we can help a bit better? :)

Comment: Sir the html markup can be seen on the above link, anyway I will edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the answer to your problem, but it should get you on the right track.

Behold! [The Holy Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail)!

If that doesn't work, another technique you can use is to fake the column. This is done by vertically tiling a background image the width of your column behind where you want your column to be. It's not bad and can work in a pinch.

Comment: Sir thank you for your answer I am reading the Holy Grail article and I found it very interesting for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 0):

css :

```
#header,#content,#main,#right,
#right .top,#right .bottom,#center,#footer 
{float:left;}
```

html :

```
div.header <br>
div.center + div.left <br>
div.footer + div.right
```

should be like this/